# Numerical POS tag training in nltk (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

To create a natural language calculator, I tried TrigramTagger from nltk. I want to tag multiplication and 2 numbers in given sentences. 
For example: "What is product of 5 and 7", here 'product' is 'binary.multiply', '5' is 'num-1', and '7' is 'num-2'. Once I can tag these 3, I can easily calculate answer.

But as you can see in the output below, I am not able to train the tagger about the 2 numbers. The number has to be exactly same as it was trained, otherwise it defaults to "CD".  Using regex or otherwise, how do I train tagger about the num-1 and num-2?

```
import nltk.tag, nltk.data
from nltk import word_tokenize
default_tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)

def evaluate(tagger, sentences):
    good,total = 0,0.
    for sentence in sentences:
        tags = tagger.tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
        print tags

train_sents = [
    [('product', 'binary.multiply'), ('of', 'IN'), ('5', 'num-1'), ('and', 'CC'), ('7', 'num-2'), ('?', '.')],
    [ ('what', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'),  ('product', 'binary.multiply'), ('of', 'IN'), ('5', 'num-1'), ('and', 'CC'), ('7', 'num-2'), ('?', '.')],
    [('what', 'WP'), ('happens', 'NNS'), ('when', 'WRB'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('multiply', 'binary.multiply'), ('5', 'num-1'), ('with', 'IN'), ('7', 'num-2'), ('?', '.')],
    [('5', 'num-1'), ('*', 'binary.multiply'), ('3.2','CD')],
    [('is', 'NNP'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('possible', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('multiply', 'binary.multiply'), ('5', 'num-1'), ('with', 'IN'), ('7', 'num-2'), ('?', '.')],
    [('what', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('5', 'num-1'), ('times', 'binary.multiply'), ('7', 'num-2'), ('?', '.')]
]

sentences = [
    ('product of 5 and 7?'),
    ('what is product of 3 and 2.7?'),
    ('what happens when I multiply 0.1 with 5.21?'),
    ('9.1 * 3.2'),
    ('is it possible to multiply 5 with 7?'),
    ('what is 5 times 7?')
]

tagger = nltk.TrigramTagger(train_sents, backoff=default_tagger)
evaluate(tagger, sentences)
#model = tagger._context_to_tag
```

The output of this program does not recognize different numbers as num-1 and num-2, how to make it recognize it?

```
[('product', 'binary.multiply'), ('of', 'IN'), ('4', 'CD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('2', 'CD'), ('?', '.')]
[('what', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('product', 'binary.multiply'), ('of', 'IN'), ('3', 'CD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('2.7', 'CD'), ('?', '.')]
[('what', 'WP'), ('happens', 'NNS'), ('when', 'WRB'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('multiply', 'binary.multiply'), ('0.1', 'CD'), ('with', 'IN'), ('5.21', 'CD'), ('?', '.')]
[('9.1', 'CD'), ('*', '-NONE-'), ('3.2', 'CD')]
[('is', 'NNP'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('possible', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('multiply', 'binary.multiply'), ('2', 'CD'), ('with', 'IN'), ('77', 'CD'), ('?', '.')]
[('what', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('15', 'CD'), ('times', 'NNS'), ('72', 'CD'), ('?', '.')]
```

Comment: POS tagging is only a first step towards analyzing a phrase anyway. You need syntax to figure out what an utterance means.

Comment: Cant make syntax specific, as I want my program very easy to train, i.e, whenever it makes a mistake, I will add corrected sentence to training set. Further, If you look at last output, it did not recognize "times" as "binary.multiply", which it should have. Also, I need to distinguish order of numbers (important when I move to divide/ minus). Is there a way to train trigram tagger that I am looking for any number rather than exactly 5 and 7. The program works perfectly when I give same input (5,7) as training set.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think you can use [RegexTagger](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) for this, RegexTagger is the regular expression tagger assigns tags to tokens on the basis of matching patterns.

Try this code

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk.tag
patterns = [
      (r'product|multiply|times', 'binary.multiply'),               # gerunds
      (r'\*', 'binary.multiply'), 
      (r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', 'num'),
      (r'\w+', 'word'),
      (r'[^0-9a-zA-z\*]','sym')
      ]
sentences = [
('product of 5 and 7?'),
('what is product of 3 and 2.7?'),
('what happens when I multiply 0.1 with 5.21?'),
('9.1 * 3.2'),
('is it possible to multiply 5 with 7?'),
('what is 5 times 7?')
]

regexp_tagger = nltk.RegexpTagger(patterns)
regexp_tagger.tag(word_tokenize(sentences[0]))
```

Output

```
[('product', 'binary.multiply'),
 ('of', 'NN'),
 ('5', 'num'),
 ('and', 'NN'),
 ('7', 'num'),
 ('?', 'sym')]
```

Now from output list, you can easily find 1st number and 2nd number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Is there a way to combine regex with trigram tagger? Relying only on regex might cause in future. for example, when I move to divide and minus, the order of numbers are important. (Subtract 5 from 2) is different from (5 minus 2). I am planning to move to more complex tasks after this, so I really need a learning algorithm.